# Django MaterializeCSS - working, but not sure the right way to set css and js?

Tags: django, materialize

I'm working on Django project with Materializecss design - Built a page with floating button for example.

Why is it not working?

I started using exactly the template from the website: https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html
and updated from the CDN part in the page:

```
<!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

And added at the bottom: 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks a lot!

The full HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
<div class="fixed-action-btn">
    <a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-large blue">
            <i class="large material-icons">filter_drama</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-large green">
            <i class="large material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

      <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: If it worked you might consider splitting this into a question and an answer. What you did is right. It is in the right place.

Comment: You're right. Updated, thank you. - I was curious why the updated files didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some posts, I use a suggestion to add the below, and it worked:

```
<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

If someone know to explain the below, it'll be great:

1. Why the updated version of the files is not working?
2. What's the right way to install it for production?

The full HTML with the 'ADDED PART THAT MAKE IT WORK':

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
<div class="fixed-action-btn">
    <a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-large blue">
            <i class="large material-icons">filter_drama</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="btn-floating btn-large green">
            <i class="large material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

      <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

ADDED PART THAT MAKE IT WORK:

<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```